# Why does SSMS drop and recreate a table when attempting to Alter a column from varchar(8000) to varchar(MAX)?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

When attempting to Alter a column in a table from varchar(8000) to varchar(MAX), SSMS generates a script that drops the constraints on the table, creates a new table, inserts all the data from the old table to the new, drops the foreign keys from the old table, drops the old table, renames the new table, then recreates the foreign keys on the new table. Is this generally safer than just running 'ALTER TABLE TableA ALTER COLUMN ColumnA varchar(MAX)'? When would I want to run the SSMS generated script vs the 'ALTER TABLE TableA ALTER COLUMN ColumnA varchar(MAX)' script?

Comment: I don't think we can answer the why - surely it was up to the designers of SSMS/the scripting engine at Microsoft. We can only guess.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forcing Management Studio to use ALTER TABLE instead of DROP/CREATE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431901/forcing-management-studio-to-use-alter-table-instead-of-drop-create)

Comment: This question is not concerning how to force SSMS to create simpler scripts. I am asking if one script is safer than the other or are they functionally equivalent.

Comment: In that case I can't think of a time when you would want to run the autogenerated version, there's almost always a more sensible way of writing whatever the change might be, as you suggest either altering columns in place, or at worst dropping keys and constraints, adding a new column, move values, drop the old column, rename the new one, recreate constraints.

Comment: @Chris - If you go to the question that's been linked to, you'll see that despite the title, it also asks if there's a reason SSMS does this, much as you have asked. The accepted answer is pretty relevant, as well.

Answer (score -2):

They are not functionally the same.  VARCHAR(8000) has a maximum of 8,000 characters.  VARCHAR(MAX) can technically store up to 2^31 - 1 (2,147,483,647) characters.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089(v=sql.110).aspx